# in main NameError: name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to call a function in main. But it keep saying that one of the argument is not defined in main. The argument is from the other function. Dose main get access to that?

```
def main():
  getMenuInput()
  getQuantityInput(maxQuantity)

def getMenuInput():
  while True:
    try:
      order = input('Select a letter from the menu: ')
    except ValueError:
        print ('Sorry, please try again')
        continue
    else:
        break


  if order == 'a': 
     itemName = 'Grilled salmon'
     itemPrice = 26.99
     maxQuantity = 50
     return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity
  elif order == 'b':
    itemName = 'New York Steak'
    itemPrice = 18.99
    maxQuantity = 50
    return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity
  elif order == 'c':
    itemName = 'Roast Chicken'
    itemPrice = 12.99
    maxQuantity = 50
    return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity     
  elif order == 'd':
    itemName = 'Salad'
    itemPrice = 5.99
    maxQuantity = 200
    return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity   
  elif order == 'e':
    itemName = 'Soup'
    itemPrice = 7.99
    maxQuantity = 200
    return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity   
  elif order == 'f':
    itemName = 'Hamburger'
    itemPrice = 4.99
    maxQuantity = 200
    return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity   
  elif order == 'g':
    itemName = 'Soft drink'
    itemPrice = 1.29
    maxQuantity = 200
    return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity   
  elif order == 'h':
    itemName = 'Tea'
    itemPrice = 1.5
    maxQuantity = 200
    return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity 
  elif order == 'i':
    itemName = 'Orange juice'
    itemPrice = 2.5
    maxQuantity = 200
    return itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity
  else:
      order = input('Invalid menu item. Enter another menu item: ')


def getQuantityInput(maxQuantity):

     while True:        
         try:
             value = int(input('Enter the Quantity: '))
         except ValueError:
             print("Sorry, your response must not be negative.")
         continue

         if value < 0 and value > maxQuantity:
             value = int(input('Quantity cannot be negative. Enter another quantity: ')) 
             continue
         else:
             break
         return value
```

Error message shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/python/test1.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/python/test1.py", line 3, in main
    getQuantityInput(maxQuantity)
NameError: name 'maxQuantity' is not defined
```

Comment: Forget to call the main() at last.

Comment: In the `main` function you are calling `getQuantityInput` with an argument `maxQuantity` but it is never defined. I think you forgot to assign the return value of the `getInputMenu` call

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo. Thank you. But I returned 'itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity' in getInputMenu. What do you mean by assign the return value?

Comment: You call the function but the returned value is never saved anywhere. You need to do something like `x, y, z = getMenuInput()` or in your case `x, y, maxQuantity = getMenuInput()`. As a side note, you should consider switching to a dictionary instead of the tedious `elif` structure

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you're misusing `ValueError`. `input` doesn't raise it and `int` raise it when the string can't be interpreted as an int for example "ten". The string "-10" will work fine and won't raise an error

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

    itemName, itemPrice, maxQuantity = getMenuInput()
    getQuantityInput(maxQuantity)
```

You will have to store the return value in a variable and then pass it while calling the next function `getQuantityInput`